# WPF: Is it possible to do a row/column span in UniformGrid?

Tags: wpf, xaml, row, uniformgrid

Is it possible to do a row/column span in UniformGrid?
Using Grid attached properties

> Grid.RowSpan

and

> Grid.ColumnSpan

doesn't work on UniformGrid.

Comment: If they did exist, they would be `UniformGrid.RowSpan` and `UniformGrid.ColumnSpan`, since you are not using a `Grid`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

No. There are no attached properties that will allow you to do that.

You could create a subclass of the UniformGrid and add them but you would have to handle all the arranging of the child controls.

It will be pretty hard to define what should happen to elements that span multiple columns when they have to wrap to the next line.

Comment: It seems to me that this has changed in the meantime, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/uniformgrid

Comment: @h.m.i.13: I do not see the ColumnSpan nor the RowSpan in the documentation you linked to.

Comment: @h.m.i.13 It looks like that is for UWP and provided as part of [Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/)