# WPF UniformGrid Layout

Tags: wpf, layout, grid, uniformgrid

I have an `ItemsControl` in which I plan on hosting a listing of fruit objects. I have a list of `Fruit` objects all with their own `DataTemplate`s.  I have a `Grape` object, an `Orange` object and a `Kiwi` object.

I want to use a `UniformGrid` so that all cells have equal size, but I want the `Kiwi` object to span only 1 cell, I want the `Grape` to span 2 cells (`ColumnSpan = 2`) and I want the `Orange` control to span 4 cells (`ColumnSpan = 2` and `RowSpan = 2`)

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 6):

Items in a `UniformGrid` cannot span multiple cells.

Why not use a regular `Grid` instead with the height/width of the rows/columns set to `*` so they're all equally sized? If you want cells to be a perfect square with the height matching the width, be sure to bind the Grid's `Height` to the `Width`, or vice versa.

It should be noted that you need to apply the Grid positioning properties in the `ItemContainerStyle`, not on the item itself, since an `ItemsControl` wraps each element inside a `ContentPresenter` before adding that item to the `ItemsPanel` (see my blog post [here](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-itemscontrol-example/) for more details)

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
    <!-- ItemsPanelTemplate -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <!-- ItemContainerStyle -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" 
                    Value="{Binding ColumnIndex}" />
            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" 
                    Value="{Binding RowIndex}" />

            <!-- Can either use a DataTrigger to determine these values, 
                 or store them on the object itself -->
            <Setter Property="Grid.RowSpan" 
                    Value="{Binding RowSpan}" />
            <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" 
                    Value="{Binding ColumnSpan}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant do row or column spanning in a uniform grid - see stackoverflow question below

[WPF: Is it possible to do a row/column span in UniformGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10603452/wpf-is-it-possible-to-do-a-row-column-span-in-uniformgrid)

However, you may be able to achieve a similar effect with a WrapPanel if your items have uniform dimensions. Heres an example

```
<ItemsControl Width="300">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.Items>
        <Rectangle Fill="Orange" Height="100" Width="100" />
        <Rectangle Fill="Red" Height="100" Width="100" />
        <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Height="100" Width="100" />
        <Rectangle Fill="Green" Height="100" Width="200" />
        <Rectangle Fill="Yellow" Height="100" Width="100" />
        <Rectangle Fill="Brown" Height="100" Width="100" />
        <Rectangle Fill="Black" Height="100" Width="200" />
    </ItemsControl.Items>
</ItemsControl>
```